# How do I view contents of log files that is too large?

Tags: centos, logs

I've a huge log file. Worth 403MB.

```
df -h
```

command shows that only 8% free space in /home

```
free -mh
```

command shows that only 474MB is free and 658MB is available.

How do i view the logs?

I tried.

```
grep -A500 'string_to_search' application.log_2023-07-13>/tmp/testError.txt
```

It showed

```
Binary file application.log_2023-07-13 matches
```

I tried other variants of grep command as well and they all showed the same output.

How do I view this log file without adding extra hardware and preferably by not deleting extra files.

Comment: The error message is not about the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different approaches. If you want to see the entire file and "walk" around you can use command `less`:

```
less application.log_2023-07-13
```

You can search inside by pressing `/` and entering text. When using `grep` you can use `-a` to process a file like text.

```
grep -a -A500 'string_to_search' application.log_2023-07-13>/tmp/testError.txt
```

If you manage such log files often you can start considering about log processing software like `splunk`, `opensearch` (which usually need own server a good amount of disk space)